# Can JGraphT java library be used for making 3D graphs

Tags: java, jgrapht

Basically I have to plot a 3D undirected graph from the list of vertices.At present I can plot a undirected graph in 2D and I have used the following code for this.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jgraph.JGraph;
import org.jgraph.graph.DefaultGraphCell;
import org.jgraph.graph.GraphConstants;

import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphModelAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.ListenableDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;


public class JGraphAdapterDemo extends JApplet {
private static final Color     DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.decode( "#FAFBFF" );
private static final Dimension DEFAULT_SIZE = new Dimension( 530, 320 );

// 
private JGraphModelAdapter m_jgAdapter;

/**
 * @see java.applet.Applet#init().
 */
public void init(  ) {
    // create a JGraphT graph
    ListenableGraph g = new ListenableDirectedGraph( DefaultEdge.class );

    // create a visualization using JGraph, via an adapter
    m_jgAdapter = new JGraphModelAdapter( g );

    JGraph jgraph = new JGraph( m_jgAdapter );

    adjustDisplaySettings( jgraph );
    getContentPane(  ).add( jgraph );
    resize( DEFAULT_SIZE );

    // add some sample data (graph manipulated via JGraphT)
    g.addVertex( "v1" );
    g.addVertex( "v2" );
    g.addVertex( "v3" );
    g.addVertex( "v4" );

    g.addEdge( "v1", "v2" );
    g.addEdge( "v2", "v3" );
    g.addEdge( "v3", "v1" );
    g.addEdge( "v4", "v3" );

    // position vertices nicely within JGraph component
    positionVertexAt( "v1", 50, 50 );
    positionVertexAt( "v2", 120, 120 );
    positionVertexAt( "v3", 200,200 );
    positionVertexAt( "v4", 20, 20 );

    // that's all there is to it!...
}


private void adjustDisplaySettings( JGraph jg ) {
    jg.setPreferredSize( DEFAULT_SIZE );

    Color  c        = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    String colorStr = null;

    try {
        colorStr = getParameter( "bgcolor" );
    }
     catch( Exception e ) {}

    if( colorStr != null ) {
        c = Color.decode( colorStr );
    }

    jg.setBackground( c );
}


private void positionVertexAt( Object vertex, int x, int y ) {
    DefaultGraphCell cell = m_jgAdapter.getVertexCell( vertex );
    Map attr = cell.getAttributes(  );
    Rectangle2D b = GraphConstants.getBounds(attr);

    GraphConstants.setBounds( attr, new Rectangle( x, y, b.OUT_BOTTOM, b.OUT_TOP ) );

    Map cellAttr = new HashMap(  );
    cellAttr.put( cell, attr );
    m_jgAdapter.edit( cellAttr, null, null, null);
}
}
```

Now what I want to know is that Can we extend this code and plot the undirected graph in 3D using JGraphT library.Is there anything else that will be more useful to me in fulfulling my task other than this.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented the above task.I have not done it using the JGraphT library but instead I did it using the Java 3D only.Below is the code which shows the 3D undirected graph of a tetrahedron made using Java 3D.

```
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;
import javax.media.j3d.LineStripArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.behaviors.mouse.MouseRotate;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;


public class test {

public test(){

SimpleUniverse u=new SimpleUniverse(); 

BranchGroup group=new BranchGroup();

Point3d coords[] = new Point3d[9];

Appearance app=new Appearance();

coords[0] = new Point3d(0.5d, 0.5d, 0.5d);
coords[1] = new Point3d(1.0d, 0.5d, 0.5d);
coords[2] = new Point3d(0.5d, 0.5d, 0.5d);
coords[3] = new Point3d(0.5d, 1.0d, 0.5d);
coords[4] = new Point3d(0.5d, 0.5d, 0.5d);
coords[5] = new Point3d(0.5d, 0.5d, 1.0d);
coords[6] = new Point3d(1.0d, 0.5d, 0.5d);
coords[7] = new Point3d(0.5d, 1.0d, 0.5d);
coords[8] = new Point3d(0.5d, 0.5d, 1.0d);

 int vertexCounts[] = {9};

 LineStripArray lines = new LineStripArray(9,
 GeometryArray.COORDINATES, vertexCounts);

 lines.setCoordinates(0, coords);

Shape3D shape=new Shape3D(lines , app);

//group.addChild(shape);

TransformGroup objRotate = new TransformGroup();
objRotate.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
objRotate.addChild(shape);

MouseRotate f1=new MouseRotate();
f1.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere());
f1.setTransformGroup(objRotate);
group.addChild(f1);

group.addChild(objRotate);

u.addBranchGraph(group);

u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

}

}
```

The image of the tetrahedron implemented using this is given below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aRvi.png)